# Find First occurrence of unmatched string

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a reference text - `DD/MM/YYYY`

When type each character replaced with input text. Like

```
23/1M/YYYY
```

I have to find the location of first unmatched string. In the above case,
the output should be **4**

I can't use `rangeOfString:` since it may ended up in `D` or `Y`.

```
[@"23/1M/YYYY" rangeOfString:@"M" options: NSLiteralSearch];
```

Or I should 3 lines of codes with `rangeOfString:`. Is there any better approach to achieve this.

Comment: you  can  loop through letters in a string. For example `let str = "sunday, monday, happy days"
for char in str {
    print("Found character: \(char)")
}`

Comment: You may use a regex: `(D|M|Y)`.

Comment: how to get index by applying regex, @Larme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use for-loop for now. Feel free to share better solutions.

```
NSInteger foundIndex = -1;
for (NSInteger charIdx = 0; charIdx < self.txtDOB.text.length; charIdx++) {
    char character = [self.txtDOB.text characterAtIndex:charIdx];
    if (character == [@"DD/MM/YYYY" characterAtIndex:charIdx] && character != '/') {
         foundIndex = charIdx;
         break;
    }
}
```